# Python : is there an alternate to: "except IndexError:" something lighter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.6

If mysql has no output...

```
if record[0][0]:
```

will return an error

```
 IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

the only solution i know to fix this issue is:

```
try:
    if record[0][0]:
        # Do stuff
except IndexError:
    pass
```

but this looks like a very heavy wrapper script

only to find out if

```
 record[0][0]
```

has no data. ( no value )

is there something lighter that can be done such as..

```
if record[0][0] = ""
```

?

**UPDATE:**

This is my MYSQL code:

```
a = _mysql.escape_string(a)
db=b()
db.query("select * from b where a='" + a + "' limit 1")
result = db.store_result()

record = result.fetch_row()
```

**UPDATE:**

turns out what worked is:

```
 if record:
```

rather than

```
if record[0]:
```

or

```
if record[0][0]:
```

Comment: if your record is `None` when no output, you can check for `None`

Comment: Are you using `fetchall()` or `fetchone()`? Could you show how do you get the data from mysql and what `record` looks like? Thanks.

Comment: result = db.store_result()
    
    record = result.fetch_row()

Comment: @user3880134 First thing you need to check is, whether query has returned some record. I feel that `record` does not have data somehow and that is the actual issue. Check `if record:` first.

Answer (score 2):

In the general case, if you want to check if an item exists in a list, just check that it exists. Exceptions are considered Pythonic code. Using another construct for access checking is likely to be less readable and suffer from performance problems.

However, if you're really interested in something else..  how about this?

```
>>> if record[0]:
...     field = record[0][0]
```

This works because an empty list (`[]`) evaluates as `False` in an `if` statement.

```
>>> record = [[]]
>>> if record[0]:             # returns an empty list, e.g. []
...     field = record[0][0]  # is not executed
```

Comment: if record[0]: also returns the "IndexError: tuple index out of range" for me

Comment: turns out "if record:" worked. ( followed the logic of removing some [0]s from the rrecord[0][0] )

Answer (score 1):

A simpler alternative:

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect(passwd="sekret",db="foo")
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("select * from b where a=%s limit 1", (a,))

for result in cur:
   print(result)
```

Note the changes:

1. Use `MySQLdb`, not the underlying `_mysql*` API
2. Don't concatenate variables into SQL query strings, this will lead to SQL injection.
3. Iterate over the cursor to get the results

Answer (score 0):

In Python, there is a way to get a default value from a dict but not from a list. E.g. in a dict:

x = mydict.get('key')  # x will be None if there is no 'key'

(you can also provide a different default as a 2nd arg to get() method)

Now, it would be convenient to have something like that for lists. Getting an item from a list
is in some ways very similar to getting an item from a dict, but not exactly the same. Python
made a design decision to not have a similar method for lists.

Of course, you can make your own very easily. I sometimes use a function in my own library
called 'getitem', which returns a default arg; however it only looks up one level of a list,
because I feel multiple levels is too much of a corner case and it's probably worth using
an exception with multiple levels. But, for one level you can do:

```
def getitem(seq, index, default=None):
    """Get item from a `seq` at `index`, return default if index out of range."""
    try               : return seq[index]
    except IndexError : return default
```

Note that there's a gotcha: you can't assume that getting None back means there is no
item, if your list may itself contain None values. Seems obvious but that's something
you have to remember.

You can easily extend this function to accept multiple indexes and handle multiple
levels of lists, but then you may ask: how do I know at which level there was an
IndexError?